# Norm of K less than or equal to norm of $\phi$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

The following problem has been presented to me:

Let $k : [a, b] × [a, b] → \mathbb{F}$ be continuous, and consider the integral operator $K : C_{\mathbb{F}}[a, b] → C_{\mathbb{F}}[a, b]$, defined by
$$ Kf(s) = \int_{a}^{b} k(s, t)f(t) dt \hspace{2cm} (s ∈ [a, b], f ∈ C_{\mathbb{F}}[a, b]) $$
Define $φ: [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ by
$$ φ(s) = \int_{a}^{b} |k(s, t)| dt (s ∈ [a, b]).$$

Prove that $||K|| \leq ||\phi||_{\infty}=\max_{s \in [a,b]}\{|\phi(s)|\}$.

I have trouble with two parts of this problem:

1. What does $||K||$ mean? Is it the supremum norm over both $f$ and $s$, such that $|K(f(s))|$ is greater than any other combination of $f$ and $s$ for $K$?
2. When assuming that that is the case, I found:
   $$ |K(f(s))| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |k(s,t)||f(t)| dt $$
   But how do I proceed? I need to get the $f(t)$ out of the integral somehow, I need to "seperate" the f(t) from the rest to obtain the supremum norm of $\phi$, but how do I do that? I know that $|f(x)| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$, but when considering the supremum norm for $K$, the supremum norm of $f$ does not come into play, correct?

Any and all help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$K$ is a linear map between normed vector spaces, here I assume you are thinking of $C[a,b]$ as having the sup-norm. Here one can ask whether or not
$$\sup_{f\in C[a,b], \|f\|≤1}\|K(f)\|$$
is finite. If it is this number is called the operator norm of $K$, the finiteness of this number is equivalent to $K$ being continuous and to $K$ being Lipschitz-continuous.

It is the smallest number so that $\|K(f)\|≤\|K\|\,\|f\|$ for all all $f$.

As for your second question, I will not show it explicitly, but what you have to see is why
$$\|K(f)\|=\sup_{s\in[a,b]}\left|\int_a^b k(s,t)f(t)\,dt\right|\overset!≤\|\phi\|\,\|f\|$$
holds for any $f$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I think I understand. Is the following solution correct?:

$$|K(f(s))|=|\int_{a}^{b}k(s,t)f(t)~dt| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |k(s,t)f(t)|~dt \leq \int_{a}^{b} |k(s,t) ||f||_{\infty}|~dt=||f||_{\infty} \int_{a}^{b} |k(s,t)|~dt \leq ||f||_{\infty} ||\phi||_{\infty}.$$

If in addition, $||K||$ is indeed that operator norm of $K$ you mention (which I am still not sure of, but I'll ask my professor), then we have 
$$||f||_{\infty} ||\phi||_{\infty} \leq ||\phi||_{\infty},$$
which concludes the proof. Right?

Comment: The first statement is true. The second should be $\|K(f)\|≤\|\phi\|\,\|f\|$.

Comment: Hm, OK, but according to $||K(f)||=\sup_{f\in C[a,b], \|f\|≤1}\|K(f)\|$, we can say that $||K(f)|| \leq ||\phi|| ||f|| \leq 1 ||\phi||=||\phi||$. Which proves that ||K|| \leq ||\phi||_{\infty}=\max_{s \in [a,b]}\{|\phi(s)|\}, right? Which means if I combine everything that has been said on this topic, I should have complete prove, correct?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ $